# Protocols with generic parameter types

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol which accept objects that are subclassed from `NSObject`:

```
protocol ProtocolExample {
    func willDisplay<T: NSObject>(object: T?)
}


class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,ProtocolExample {  
    func willDisplay<T>(object: T?) where T : NSObject {

    }

    func willDisplay(object: AMDObject?) {

    }
}

class AMDObject: NSObject {}
```

So my question is how can I apply that I only need to add the second willDisplay method instead of the first. How can I tell that in that case of tableviewcell my T is currently `AMDObject` type (like T is now `AMDObject`)

Comment: Your protocol is not generic. It is a normal protocol that requires a generic method. You cannot resolve the generic method; you must implement it exactly as your requirement dictates. To make a generic protocol you need an associated type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the requirement in `ProtocolExample` should be read to mean, "a function `willDisplay` which accepts `object`, a parameter which can be of any (optional) type `T?` as long as `T` inherits from `NSObject`". This definition guarantees that I could write a function like this:

```
func displayThings(in example: ProtocoExample) {
    example.willDisplay(NSArray())
    example.willDisplay(NSObject())
}
```

However, with your implementation, what would happen if I wrote:

```
let cell: TableViewCell = // ...
displayThings(in: cell)
```

Then, `displayThings` would be unable to call `example.willDisplay(NSArray())` since `TableViewCell` can only handle `willDisplay` for and `AMDObject`.

If you have control over the protocol yourself, you could implement this with an `associatedtype`:

```
protocol ProtocolExample {
    associatedtype DisplayObject: NSObject

    func willDisplay(object: DisplayObject?)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, ProtocolExample {
    // Implicit typealias DisplayObject = AMDObject
    func willDisplay(object: AMDObject?) {

    }
}
```

Depending on how you are using `ProtocolExample`, though, adding this `associatedtype` may not be a straightforward solution.

Comment: Can you please explicate why is this not a straightforward solution? I mean I trying to learn this kind of best practices for protocols and generic types, but sometimes its hard to understand the syntax behind the scenes.

Comment: And what If I'm using the generic protocol function. Should I guard object is AMDObject else return ? Then work with that object? Or what is the most effective way to solve issues like this

Comment: In general, if you want your function to only accept one type as determined by the conforming type/method, having a generic function in your protocol is the wrong tool. The non-straightforwardness has to do with the fact that if you add an `associatedtype` to a protocol, you will no longer be able to use the protocol as what is called an "existential type", which essentially means that it can't be used as the type of a variable as in `var x: ProtocolExample = AMDObject()`.